# Take property from source list and add to new list then convert to Json

Tags: c#

Given:

```
List<AddressData> sourceList = new List<AddressData>();
```

I need to take a property in the sourceList (FullAddress) and make that a Json string array

```
class AddressData
{
  public string Street {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
  public string State {get; set;}
  public string Zip {get; set;}
  public string FullAddress { get { return Street + "," + City "," + "State" + "," + Zip } }
}
```

My thought process:
1. Create a new List() called payload
2. Iterate over the list and add FullAddress to payload list
3. Serialize the payload list

Ask: Is there a more concise way to do this?

Sample payloadJson:

```
[
  { 'address': 'value1'},
  { 'address': 'value2'},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already know about Linq, the Select extension would do this pretty well.

I have created a demo here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/FMZK50

```
public static List<CondensedData> GetAddresses(List<AddressData> data)
{
    return data.Select(m=>new CondensedData(){Address=m.FullAddress}).ToList();
}
public class CondensedData
{
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json, the serializing is pretty simple:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(condensed);
```